# PutObject operation: Access Denied with identity provider

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, oauth, amazon-iam

I'm using a Identity provider in AWS that is able to grant a role with the following policy to the users he manages.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "GiveS3Access",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"
        }
    ]
}
```

With a valid access token on my computer I can list the objects in the s3 bucket (example below), but I can't push any object on it.

```
❯ aws s3 ls s3://mybucket/
                           PRE test_folder/
                           PRE home/
2020-10-07 15:22:13      57385 Image001.png
2020-10-07 15:25:20      98942 Image002.png

❯ aws s3 cp test.mp4 s3://mybucket/test.mp4
upload failed: ./test.mp4 to s3://mybucket/test.mp4 An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied
```

There is no default encryption and no bucket extra policy. The config file (`~/.aws/config`) is correctly configured to ask the role with the `GiveS3Access` policy (first code block).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The arn in the form of `arn:aws:s3:::mybucket` is for bucket only, not its objects. To enable download/upload of objects there should be:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "GiveS3Access",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

However, this allows **all operations** on your bucket and objects . Please reconsider changing it to follow [principles of least privileged](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-define-least-privileged-permissions-for-actions-called-by-aws-services/).